# How do I get this program to write to a file?

Tags: java, file-io

I can get this program to create a file in the correct folder, and in my read file I can read text if it is already pre-written. However, I cant seem to get this to write and save to a file, and I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatyly appreciated!

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.nio.file.AccessMode.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WriteEmpList
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Path file=Paths.get("C:\\Java\\EmployeeLists.txt");
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      String[] array =new String[3];
      String s=" ";
      String firstName,lastName,id;
      try 
      {
         OutputStream output=new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file));
         BufferedWriter writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));

         System.out.println("Enter ID number or 999 to quit");

         id=in.nextLine();

         while (!id.equals("999"))
         {
            System.out.println("Enter first name");
            firstName=in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter last name");
            lastName=in.nextLine();

            s=id+","+firstName+","+lastName+System.getProperty("line.separator");
            writer.write(s,0,s.length());

            System.out.println("Enter id number or 999 to quit: ");
            id=in.nextLine();
         }
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println("Error: "+e);
      }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Close the `BufferedWriter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the try{} catch{} block as

```
 try 
  {
     output=new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file));
      writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));

     System.out.println("Enter ID number or 999 to quit");

     id=in.nextLine();

     while (!id.equals("999"))
     {
        System.out.println("Enter first name");
        firstName=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter last name");
        lastName=in.nextLine();

        s=id+","+firstName+","+lastName+System.getProperty("line.separator");
        writer.write(s,0,s.length());

        System.out.println("Enter id number or 999 to quit: ");
        id=in.nextLine();
     }
    writer.close();

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     System.out.println("Error: "+e);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this but you should always close the stream.

If you just want something simple to write text to a file there are easier ways, like PrintWriter:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
writer.println(some text);
writer.close();
```

Some alternatives are document here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two lines of code after the end of while loop before the end of try block.

```
        .
        .
        .
        System.out.println("Enter id number or 999 to quit: ");
        id=in.nextLine();
     }
     writer.close();
     output.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      .
      .
      .
```

Basically you need to close the buffer and the stream for the output to be written in the file.